# Parsing yaml file in python

Tags: python, string, dictionary, yaml, string-matching

I have a YAML file like the following:

```
categories:
    - Exp:
        topics:
            - Experience:
                keywords:
                    - refresh
                    - tapping
            - Availability:
                keywords:
                    - fish
                    - get work
    - Wp:
        topics:
            - Waits:
                keywords:
                    - wait
                    - long line
            - Process:
                keywords:
                    - check in
                    - check-in
```

I want to know if there is a better/simpler way to parse the yaml file in python. I basically want to search keywords in `topics` in the yaml file in a string and if even one keyword of that topic exists then print that topic's name along with the `category's` name. And do this for each topic. From the above example of the yaml file, the categories are `Exp` and `Wp`, and the topics under them are `Experience` and `Availability` & `Waits` and `Process` resp.

The string I'm trying to test against is:

```
s = "Refresh after tapping takes long wait. Can't get work"
```

So output should be :

```
topic: Experience
topic: Availability
category: Exp
topic: Waits
category: Wp
```

I'm trying to parse the yaml as follows:

```
import yaml

with open("file.yaml", 'r') as stream:
    try:
        yml = yaml.load(stream)
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)

for key, val in yml.items():
    for i in val:
        for k, v in i.items():
            for k1, v1 in v.items():
                if k1 == 'topics':
                    for j in v1:
                        for k2, v2 in j.items():
                            for k3, v3 in v2.items():
                                if k3 == 'keywords':
                                    print v3
```

However, as you can see there are so many for loops to reach the topic keywords, this is very bad piece of code. How can this be done in a better way?

Comment: You already have parsed the YAML document when `yaml.load()` returns. And that is by far the worse part of your code, not the for loops. The use of `yaml.load()` is unsafe, if you don't have control over your input. You seldom have need of unsafe parsing, certainly not with your and by using it you can lose your disc content or worse.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
def walk(root, kw, path=''):
    found = []

    if isinstance(root, list):
        for i, item in enumerate(root):
            found.extend(walk(item, kw, path='%s/%d' % (path, i)))
    elif isinstance(root, dict):
        for k, v in root.items():
            if k == 'keywords':
                # this produces a flat list of all the keywords
                # in a topic.
                words = sum((x.split() for x in v), [])

                # see if the list of target keywords contains
                # any of the topic keywords
                if any(x in kw for x in words):
                    return [path]
            found.extend(walk(v, kw, path='%s/%s' % (path, k)))

    return found
```

Given that:

```
phrase = "Refresh after tapping takes long wait. Can't get work"
kw = phrase.lower().split()
```

If we call `walk` like this:

```
found = walk(data, kw)
```

We get as a result:

```
['/categories/0/Exp/topics/0/Experience', 
 '/categories/0/Exp/topics/1/Availability', 
 '/categories/1/Wp/topics/0/Waits']
```

You could pretty easily extract the category or topic from those paths:

```
for path in found:
    cat = path.split('/')[3]
    topic = path.split('/')[6]
    print 'category:', cat
    print 'topic:', topic
```

Which gets me:

```
category: Exp
topic: Experience
category: Exp
topic: Availability
category: Wp
topic: Waits
```

And you could obviously uniq-ify that list as necessary.

Those paths also happen to be valid [jsonpointer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901) paths, which means you can do clever things with `jsonpointer.resolve_pointer`:

```
>>> jsonpointer.resolve_pointer(data, found[0])
{'keywords': ['refresh', 'tapping']}
```

Comment: Can this cat = path.split('/')[3]
    topic = path.split('/')[6] not be hardcoded though? Because I have a file of phrases for which I need to check and some might match more topics some might match less.

Comment: That's fine, you'll get multiple paths.  In any case, the category is always going to be the third component of the path, and similarly for the topic name.  Try feeding it different sample data and see what happens.

Comment: I did, but I got an error     topic = path.split('/')[6]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Can you update the sample data in your question? I'd be happy to take a second look. It's tough to validate things if I don't know what the input data looks like.

Comment: There is a case like this: '/categories/0/Exp' i.e., where there is no topic

Comment: If you could update the sample data in your question, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it like this.

The structure that `yaml` returns is somewhat complicated; however, it can be seen to be a collection of dictionaries and lists. One can select the 'keywords' element fro each of the four branches by making judicious choices of element numbers for lists and element names for dictionaries. Then, in a for loop, each of these combinations of choices is used to pick out one of the list of keywords. The choices of element names for the dictionaries prove to be the items that you want to associate with the keywords!

In the final step, we look through the keys of the dictionary we have created to see which items appear in the given sentence, and return the values from the dictionary for these keys.

```
>>> import yaml
>>> yml = yaml.load(open('file.yaml'))
>>> lookups = {}
>>> for item_5, item_1, item_3, item_2 in [[0, 'Exp', 0, 'Experience'], [0, 'Exp', 1, 'Availability'], [1, 'Wp', 0, 'Waits'], [1, 'Wp', 1, 'Process']]:
...     keywords = yml['categories'][item_5][item_1]['topics'][item_3][item_2]['keywords']
...     for word in keywords:
...         lookups[word] = {'category': item_1, 'topic': item_2}
... 
>>> lookups
{'check-in': {'category': 'Wp', 'topic': 'Process'}, 'long line': {'category': 'Wp', 'topic': 'Waits'}, 'get work': {'category': 'Exp', 'topic': 'Availability'}, 'tapping': {'category': 'Exp', 'topic': 'Experience'}, 'check in': {'category': 'Wp', 'topic': 'Process'}, 'fish': {'category': 'Exp', 'topic': 'Availability'}, 'refresh': {'category': 'Exp', 'topic': 'Experience'}, 'wait': {'category': 'Wp', 'topic': 'Waits'}}
>>> s = "Refresh after tapping takes long wait. Can't get work".lower()

>>> for word in lookups:
...     if word in s:
...         word, lookups[word]
...         
('get work', {'category': 'Exp', 'topic': 'Availability'})
('tapping', {'category': 'Exp', 'topic': 'Experience'})
('refresh', {'category': 'Exp', 'topic': 'Experience'})
('wait', {'category': 'Wp', 'topic': 'Waits'})
```